# Why does zsh allow name to be null in ${name:-word}?

Tags: zsh, variable-substitution

From [zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

> ${name-word}
>
> ${name:-word}
>
> If name is set, or in the second form is non-null, then substitute its
>   value; otherwise substitute word. In the second form name may be
>   omitted, in which case word is always substituted.

So I can use something like:

```
$ printf '%s\n' ${:-123}
123
```

I wonder why `zsh` allow this and in which case it's useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an explanation for *why* they did it this way, but `${:-foo...}` does have an application: it counts as a parameter substitution in places that syntactically require one, but always just expands to a literal you give. You can write things like this to use [expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) or [other expansion specifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-RC_005fEXPAND_005fPARAM_002c-toggle) on a literal string in-place:

```
$ echo ${(#)${=${:-65 66 67}}}
A B C
$ echo ${(q)${:-hello world!}}
hello\ world\!
```

You can also [use other expansions inside your `word` string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159750):

```
$ restofarglist=arg3,arg4
$ echo ${${:-arg1,arg2,$restofarglist}//,/ }
```

All of this behaviour is documented right [at the end of the section on parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-GLOB_005fSUBST_002c-toggle):

> If a `${...}` type parameter expression or a `$(...)` type command substitution is used in place of *name* above, it is expanded first and the result is used as if it were the value of *name*.

You can nest these expansions arbitrarily deeply, although they become incomprehensible fairly quickly. There are strange corner cases around using the `${name=word}` family of expansions inside either side.

It's a pretty obtuse way of doing things in general, but it's both the only application I know of for `${:-}` and the only way to make these things happen without creating another variable. The documentation could definitely be clearer, even though all the bits are technically there.

Answer (score 3):

When combined with other features of parameter expansions, it allows you to do a few clever tricks.

A couple examples:

```
# strftime date via prompt sequences
tar -cpf ${(%):-%D{%Y%m%d}}-/etc.tar /etc
# brace expansion, but separated by commas via PE flags and nesting PEs.
print ${(j:,:)${:-{1..10}}}
```